# Как отключить кнопку Delete/Backspace или изменить поведение в Chrome console application при редактирование?

Tags: google-chrome, консоль

При редактирование значений в Chrome -> Console -> Application и нажатие кнопки DELETE или Backspace, чтобы удалить что-то в тексте - удаляется весь "объект".

И ладно бы одна какая-то клавиша, так обе удаляют полностью объект без каких-либо вопросов.

Как отключить это удаление или изменить поведение? Уже в сотый раз удаляется куча данных.

[image]
Нашёл только одно расширение, которым можно было бы попытаться заменить стандартные инструменты - "HTML5 Storage Manager All in One", но оно отказалось работать на страницах с расширениями (chrome-extension://)

Comment: правильно, потому что на странице расширений расширения не могут работать, политика безопасности

Comment: а зачем вам это на странице расширений?

Comment: берите исходники хрома и пилите под себя. И потом давайте этот хром кому нужно. Иначе этого не сделать.

Comment: ThisMan на странице расширений расширения отлично работают. И логично что для расширения.